# How to find area of trapezoid using length of diagonals and length of line connecting midpoints of parallel sides.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, area

How do you find the area of a trapezoid using the length of its diagonals and the length of the line connecting the midpoints of its parallel sides?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Construct points $A'$ and $B'$ as reflections of $A$ and $B$ with respect to $N$, the midpoint of $CD$. It is easy to show that $A'B'DC$ is a trapezoid that, upon a $180^o$ rotation, is congruent with $ABCD$ .

Draw a segment from $B$ to $A'$ and let it intersect $CD$ at $X$ .

[image]

It is easy to show that $BX = XA'$ . The interested reader can also show that $BA' = 2MN$ .

Consider triangle $BDA'$ . Note that the lengths of the three sides of this triangle are given (diagonals and twice MN). Therefore, we are able to calculate the area of this triangle.

Now, we argue that the area of the trapezoid $ABCD$ equals the area of the triangle $BDA'$ . To prove this argument, first note that
$S_{BDX} = S_{DA'X}$ and $S_{BCX} = S_{CA'X}$.
Then construct parallelogram $BXDX'$ and note that
$$S_{BXDX'} = 2S_{BDX} = S_{BDA'}$$
Moreover, $\triangle ADX' = \triangle CA'X$ , which means $S_{ADX'} = S_{CA'X} = S_{BCX}$ . Therefore:
$$S_{ABCD} = S_{BXDX'} = S_{BDA'}$$
Now all we need to do is calculate $S_{BDA'}$, which is easy, because we have all its side lengths and we can apply Heron's formula to calculate the area of the triangle.

Comment: good resolution.

Comment: @sirous Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Consider trapezoid ABCD(clock wise order). Drop a perpendicular from B on CD and mark it as E, Do the same from C on extension of AB and mark it as F, so DB, AC and BE=CF are given; we have:

$DE=\sqrt {DB^2-BE^2}$

$AF=\sqrt{AC^2-BE^2}$

$AF+DE=AB+CD$

And the area of trapezoid is:

$A=(AF+DE)\frac {BE}2$

Comment: It seems you have assumed that the length of the segment connecting midpoints of the parallel sides of the trapezoid is equal to the perpendicular distance between the two parallel sides. This assumption is not generally true.

Comment: @Saeed, True, it is for especial case when trapezoid is isosceles.